# Angular UI-Grid row fillers

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

Is there a way to have UI Grid fill in empty rows to fill your grid's height?

[image]

CSS:

```
.myGrid{
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ui-grid="{data: folderData}" class="myGrid"></div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.folderData =[
    {
    "folderName": "My Photos",
    "folderPath": "/path/pictures",
    "fileCount": "400",
    "fileSize": "150MB"
    }
    //...
];
```

Answer (score 2):

As a hack you can always add empty rows at the end of the gridOptions data and it will add empty fields

```
for (i=0; i<30; i++)
   scope.gridOptions.data. push({ name : 'folderName' , 'folderPath': '', 'fileCount' : '', 'filesize': '' });
```

Or event better add an background image as the background of the DIV

```
     .ui-grid-render-container-body
```

that looks like the rows grid you use

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, adding dummy rows. Thanks for replying.